# Force Chrome AutoFill to use Heuristic Type?

Tags: google-chrome, autofill

I am having an issue with Google Chrome interpreting a Name field as an email field in regards to AutoFill.

Looking at the AutoFill predictions I can see that the heuristic type is correctly detecting the type 'name' but the Google Chrome server is strangely determining this field to be an email type:

[image: Incorrect Server Type]

Is there a way to force Google Chrome to use the Heuristic Type and ignore the server type?

Comment: how did you get the hueristic type information from the Google Chrome server ?

Answer (score 0):

I was never able to figure out why server type was coming back as an EMAIL_ADDRESS but I was able to force the type by setting the autocomplete attribute to name:

`<input type="text" autocomplete="name" />`

Google Developer's site has some more details: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/06/checkout-faster-with-autofill?hl=en